# Imagick - Can't read image files from URL.

Tags: php, imagick

I'm using this snippet for reading images on different websites:

```
$image = new Imagick('http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 05156 06204 80 1175 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]');
```

But sometimes, I get an error like this (about 20% of the time):

```
ImagickException

Unable to read the file: http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 05156 06204 80 1175 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]

Imagick->__construct()
```

The error seems to be consistent through this whole domain, but sometimes it's different from image to image on the same domain.

### Questions

Why is this a problem?
How can we fix it?
Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: As described in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340733/570796 The issue was with the uri format. I solved it by encoding it correctly, but the answer marked as correct is a much better solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

STEP 1 : GET URL

```
$url = 'http://blablabla.com/blabla.jpeg';
```

STEP 2 : Save blog content to a variable

```
$image = file_get_contents($url);
```

STEP 3 : Create Imagick object

```
$img = new Imagick();
```

STEP 4 : Instruct imagick object to read blob content of the image

```
$img -> readImageBlob($image);
```

STEP 5 : Save (or do operations) on image

```
$img -> writeImage('/var/www/html/uploads/img.jpg');
```

STEP 6 : Destroy imagick instance

```
$img -> destroy();
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the url: "`http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 05156 06204 80 1175 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]`" which is the question. The problem is that Imagick can't handle the uri format.

Comment: http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01%2005156%2006204%2080%201175%204.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]

Worked for me : http://i.imgur.com/qqwrdVl.png

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out I needed to encode the url properly. I'm not sure if this code is optimal, but it works.. and could hopefully help someone else.

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url('http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 05156 06204 80 1175 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]');
$info      = pathinfo($parsedUrl['path']);
$dirname   = explode('/', $info['dirname'] ?: '');
$dirname   = array_filter($dirname, 'strlen');
$dirname   = array_map('urlencode', $dirname);
$dirname   = implode('/', $dirname);
$basename  = urlencode($info['basename'] ?: '');
$path      = array_filter(array($dirname, $basename), 'strlen');
$path      = '/' . implode('/', $path);

$query = explode('&', $parsedUrl['query'] ?: '');
foreach ($query as &$set)
{
  $set = explode('=', $set, 2);
  $set = array_map('urlencode', $set);
  $set = implode('=', $set);
}

$query    = implode('&', $query);
      
$uri      = array_filter(array($path, $query), 'strlen');
$uri      = implode('?', $uri);

$fragment = urlencode($info['fragment'] ?: '');
$uri      = array_filter(array($uri, $fragment), 'strlen');
$uri      = implode('#', $uri);

$scheme   = $parsedUrl['scheme'] ?: '';
$host     = $parsedUrl['host']   ?: '';
$url      = array_filter(array($scheme, $host), 'strlen');
$url      = implode('://', $url);
$url     .= $uri;

$image    = new Imagick($url);
```

---

#### OBS!

This code will leave notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) function for encode special chars of url:

```
$image = new Imagick(urlencode('http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 05156 06204 80 1175 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]'));
```

Or if not work, try this:

```
$content = file_get_contents(urlencode('http://lp.hm.com/hmprod?set=key[source],value[/model/2012/P01 05156 06204 80 1175 4.jpg]&set=key[rotate],value[]&set=key[width],value[]&set=key[height],value[]&set=key[x],value[]&set=key[y],value[]&set=key[type],value[STILL_LIFE_FRONT]&call=url[file:/product/large]'));
$image = new Imagick($content);
```

Comment: No, I've tried this. It opens up new errors, it dose't even understand the url. I guess what I should do in that case is to break up every part of the url and encode all different parts in some way.

Comment: The first comment was about the ´urlencode´ only. But I will try the ´file_get_contents´ alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar issue. I was using file_get_contents() and was getting the same "ImagickException  The filename is too long". The fix for me was finding the tmp directory and setting the correct permissions for it.